# Finding the solution for a syntax error of a module in black-parrot

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

After including the required variable, I am still getting the same error:

> C:/Users/CDAC/Documents/bp_be/bp_common_aviary_cfg_pkgdef.svh(375):
> (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'cc_x_dim'.

```
`include `BP_CUSTOM_DEFINES_PATH
  `ifndef BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG
    `define BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG bp_default_cfg_p
`define bp_aviary_define_override
  `endif
`ifndef
`define cc_x_dim
`endif


  // Custom, tick define-based configuration
  localparam  bp_custom_cfg_p =
   '{`bp_aviary_define_override(cc_x_dim, BP_CC_X_DIM, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
      ,`bp_aviary_define_override(cc_y_dim, BP_CC_Y_DIM, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
      ,`bp_aviary_define_override(ic_y_dim, BP_IC_Y_DIM, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
      ,`bp_aviary_define_override(mc_y_dim, BP_MC_Y_DIM, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
      ,`bp_aviary_define_override(cac_x_dim, BP_CAC_X_DIM, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
      ,`bp_aviary_define_override(sac_x_dim, BP_SAC_X_DIM, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
      ,`bp_aviary_define_override(cacc_type, BP_CACC_TYPE, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
      ,`bp_aviary_define_override(sacc_type, BP_SACC_TYPE, `BP_CUSTOM_BASE_CFG)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What value is the variable cc_x_dim?  It should be cc_x_dim = 12345.  See following to better understand predirectives : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives

Comment: the value of cc_x_dim = 1

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `cc_x_dim` as a text macro using  `` `define ``.  Therefore you must reference it using the backtick  `` `cc_x_dim ``